# redirecting using urlencode problem

Tags: php, url, urlencode

Am trying to pass the value hrough the URL but when i retrieve it it appears like this ' , urlencode(15.99),'

the value is correct but i have tried different things but still unable to just send the value without the urlencode or added syntax 
the line of code am trying to send the value is

redirect_to("$the_file_is?subj=' . urlencode($the_price_is)' ");

Answer (score 0):

This should do what you're looking for, assuming I understood it correctly:
`redirect_to($the_file_is . '?subj=' . urlencode($the_price_is));`

Answer (score 0):

Surely just change to...

```
redirect_to($the_file_is."?subj=" . urlencode($the_price_is));
```

Comment: thanks am new to php sometimes I forget the basics so thanks again

Comment: No worries, happens to everyone!

Answer (score 0):

Almost there - just a little bit of quote confusion :)

`redirect_to("$the_file_is?subj=" . urlencode($the_price_is));`

It's worth noting that you can reference variables in double quotes so:

`echo "hello $name";` will work, but `echo "$actioned";` might need to be `echo "{$action}ed"; echo $action.'ed';` depending.

Comment: thanks skipychalmers php sometimes seems so much to learn when learning